# Sorting products by name in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to sort my products alphabetically by name in Magento. The problem is, my products' names are in Japanese characters so for obvious reasons, the sorting would not work. Also, I have another name for products which I call name_en, which is basically the english name for the products for my english store view. My question is, how can I sort the products by name? I see 2 possible ways to approach this:

1. Sort the Japanese characters by bit (I believe this would be tedious)
2. Sort the product by name_en but I'm not sure which file I need to modify for this.

These are basically just ideas that come to mind on how I can accomplish what I want but I have no idea how I can implement this. Please help.

Comment: Not enough info to be an answer, but I'm wondering what setting the collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is an immediate solution but instead, a workaround following the second option I came up with. I modified my name_en attribute to display english and japanese text on the frontend. Then set name_en as the criteria for sorting instead of name on the categories. So now, both my japanese and english sites sort products using the English name.